# Game engine for turn based wargame

Tags: turn-based

I would like to ask for game engine recommendations for turn based wargame development. I would like my engine to support;

- hex maps
- agents on hex
- rule based ai for the agents
- terrain on hex
- cultural features on hex
- los analysis
- abstract agent templetes

Comment: Chances are, this doesn't exist. Also, language?

Comment: Did you decide to use something canned or did you start from scratch?

Comment: Which technology to use questions are considered off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Vassal](http://www.vassalengine.org/) - it may do the trick for you.  @AttackingHobo pointed it out to me a while back in a previous question.